# Specifiying firefox 3.6.3 in custom browser path selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

after specifying custom browser path to firefox 3.6.3 selenium couldnt able to open the testsuite.

<*custom c:/program files/mozilla/firefox.exe>

but error message appeared through RC server that it cannot open the firefox version.

also i am confuse to use custom path through selenium ,

any one please help me out,

Answer (score 0):

To use your firefox 3.6.3, you can use `*firefox "Path to firefox.exe"` or `*chrome "Path to firefox.exe"`
Also, make sure you are using the correct path to firefox.exe.